# Change item priority in TFS 2012 with drag and drop

Tags: tfs, drag-and-drop, scrum

Is there any view when I can change the item priorities in the scope of one sprint besides the product backlog view? It will be great to have such a possibility in sprint backlog view, however in that one I can only move items to another sprint using drag and drop, without changing the ordering (priority).

Answer (score 0):

No. The iteration (sprint) backlog is intended to be a list of things the team is currently working on. Prioritization should have already occurred.

UPDATE:
With TFS 2012.3 and higher, items that are in a "Committed" state stay on the backlog. You can re-prioritize them there, and it will be reflected in your Sprint backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/07/08/where-is-the-field-on-the-work-item-form-to-order-the-backlog/

You need to go to backlog items view and you can right click on an item to choose between "move to top" or "move to position.."